# hazelcast distributed query getting slow every hour

Tags: hazelcast

Every 2 seconds my WebSocket App. sends query to my hazelcast cluster (2 nodes, 8 CPU, 16 GB RAM) to get the latest date to send customers.

when the application starts it takes 100 ms but after 1-2 days it takes 3-15 s, and then when I restart it again takes 100ms, what is happening to this query?

my WebSocket app uses %5 of total CPU and nodes use % 60 CPU.

but nodes CPU is increasing using CPU every hour.

Comment: Try turning on diagnostic logging and post the logs. Use `hazelcast.diagnostics.enabled` set to `true` and `hazelcast.diagnostics.metric.level` of `info` for instance.

Comment: Also, it's worth checking your objects counts. It could be data being created and not deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Nuri,

Without seeing the query & the data size, it's not easy to suggest anything but some generic suggestions:

- Add index to the date field that you're querying, this'll drastically improve the query performance, but will require either using Portable serialization or POJO class being available on Hazelcast nodes.
- If you need this info every 2 seconds & I assume that you're updating frequently as well, use Hazelcast Jet, define a streaming to find the max date. Since this job will only look to incoming new updates/inserts/deletes, not the whole list, it'll most probably be faster. Then you can store this info in another Hazelcast Map & use key based access, which is very fast.

If you share some info, query itself, data set size, update rate etc, I can give more detailed suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

i put many indexes and i alsu increased hz query size, they are not helping and data is less then 1 million, so something is wrong and i use hz data serilization but didnt help

Comment: Can you share your query, if possible & index config.